# How to measure the time of 100 executions of the program?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, time

I have the program and want to run it 1000 times and measure the time (basically time ./a.out < in times 1000).
What is the easiest approach?
The system is Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: You can just use bash `for` loop. What have you tried?

Comment: Example code? Sorry for lack of knowledge but I only use Linux for cachegrind testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify your main like this

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

   int times = 1;
   if (argc > 1)
      times = atoi(argv[1]);
   for(int counter = 0; counter < times; counter++) {
   .....
   ........
   .......
   }
}
```

and run it like this `time ./a.out 1000`

or using bash
file 1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..1000}
do
   ./a.out
done
```

run like this `time bash 1.sh`

Comment: You mean modify his program? Bad solution just for testing. What if the program takes time to re-compile? And you're assuming he has the source code to being with.

Comment: The part I'm testing it the input reading from stdio so this is not a solution in this case.

Comment: @user2835249: Then use the second part of the answer